# Add UISearchBar above keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

[image: How do I achieve this]

I want to display a search bar above the keyboard.  Whenever the keyboard appears search bar should also come.  How to do this?

Comment: can u show ur tried code

Comment: I've created search bar programatically and am thinking to add it as an input view of keyboard... But no idea to implement in code...

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use textField.inputAccessoryView = your search bar

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = mySearchBar;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of UISearch bar and add an observer for keyboard in textFieldDidBeginEditing/textViewDidBeginEditing

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{

CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

int height = MIN(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);
int width = MAX(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);

//set frame for searchbar
     searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - height, width, 50);    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = 0.0f;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];
}
```